# Getting problem in enabling cross origin for spring boot backend and react frontend

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, rest

I have created react frotend and im creating spring boot backend but it is giving the error

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/home' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

React code:

```
    import axios from "axios"

class Helloworldservice{
    executehelloworldservice(){
        return axios.get('http://localhost:8080/home');
    }

}
export default new Helloworldservice()
```

boot code:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class RestServiceController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public User giveServiceBack() {
        return new User(1, "satyajit");
    }

}
```

Also added configuration seprately

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class Webconfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
    }
    enter code here

}
```

Non of this is solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `allowedHeaders` and  `allowCredentials`.

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200",allowedHeaders = "*", allowCredentials = "true")
public class RestServiceController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public User giveServiceBack() {
        return new User(1, "satyajit");
    }

}
```